# How can I listen to changes in my bloc stream

Tags: flutter, bloc, stream-builder

I am new to flutter and am trying to build an app using Bloc architecture.

I could manage to figure out a sink, inputting my event `bloc.updateNavigation(_selectedItem.value);`. I also figured out how to use that data by calling my bloc (is that what its called). I had a TextFormField and changed some settings like this `if (bloc.navigationProvider.currentNavigation == 1)`, `if (bloc.navigationProvider.currentNavigation == 2)`

There is one thing I couldn't figure out how to do though. I would like to set `_Controller.clear();` whenever the bloc changes. So that whenever a user makes a new selection and changes the "currentNavigation" the text controller clears. Is there a way I can find out just when a change is made, rather than having to call by the changes. I would like to do something like `if (change is made to currentNavigation) {_Controller.clear();}`

My bloc file looks like this:

```
class NavigationBloc {
  final navigationController = StreamController();
  NavigationProvider navigationProvider = new NavigationProvider();

  Stream get getNavigation => navigationController.stream;

  void updateNavigation(int navigation) {
    navigationProvider.updateNavigation(navigation);
    navigationController.sink.add(navigationProvider.currentNavigation);
  }

  void dispose() {
    navigationController.close();
  }
}

final bloc = NavigationBloc();
```

Answer (score 0):

Streams have a `.listen(..)` method which gets called everytime data is passed into the stream.

For better usage, use the [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc) package. It provides widgets to provide a bloc to all descendants (BlocProvider) and widgets to listen to state-changes (BlocListener). There you don't have to mess with streams at all and there are a few plugins that help creating the boilerplate code.

Comment: The thing is I am not actually interested in the data that is passed into the stream, just in the fact that data has been passed. I don't need the data, I just want to be able to say, on data being passed, clear the controller.

Comment: flutter_bloc package does seem interesting and probably a better way to deal with what I have been working with, but for now it seems still like rather a daunting task to update all my bloc's to using that package.

Comment: You can ignore the data in the listen method and clear it :) There is no separate method that fires every time the stream gets updated